# How to break up a vector into contiguous groups in R

Tags: r

I am curious if there is a functional way to break up a vector of contiguous groups in R.

For example if I have the following

```r
# start with this
vec <- c(1,2,3,4,6,7,8,30,31,32)

# end with this
vec_vec <- list(c(1, 2, 3, 4),c(6,7,8),c(30,31,32))
print(vec_vec[1])
```

I can only imaging this is possible with a for loop where I calculate differences of previous values, but maybe there are better ways to solve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
split(vec, vec - seq_along(vec)) |> unname()
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 6 7 8
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 30 31 32
```

Subtratcing `seq_along(vec)` turns contiguous sequences into single values, which we can `split` by.

Comment: Clever, I was going to try diff but this is more elegant and efficient

Comment: Thanks @Ottie, I've given more-or-less this answer before, but I couldn't find it to mark it as a duplicate. While I do like this version and find it elegant, G. Grothendieck's suggestions are probably both more efficient :)

Answer (score 5):

**1)** The collapse package has seqid for this:

```
library(collapse)
split(vec, seqid(vec))
```

giving:

```
$`1`
[1] 1 2 3 4

$`2`
[1] 6 7 8

$`3`
[1] 30 31 32
```

**2)** A base approach giving the same answer is

```
split(vec, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(vec) != 1)))
```

**3)** In the comments `seqle` in cgwtools is suggested.

```
library(cgwtools)
lens <- seqle(vec)$lengths
split(vec, rep(seq_along(lens), lens))
```

Comment: `cgwtools` has `seqle` function that is rle for sequences.